# TSQL/.NET - Should one use SqlTransaction when retrieving data?

Tags: .net, t-sql

As far as I know, we use SqlTransaction to enable rollback if a statement in a batch of commands fails. My question is, is it necessary to use SqlTransaction when retrieving data/using select statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. Each Sql statement has an implicit transaction. But it can be useful if either the default transaction is not optimal - such as a Read Uncommitted would be better - or if you have multiple reads and you want the data to be consistent - such as separate statements for the summary and detail and you want the detail to add up to the summary.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the use of a Transaction to guarantee that data returned is consistent? i.e. How does a transaction help on a situation where 2 result sets are to be returned and the totals -say for summary and detail- must match?

Comment: If there are other users connected to the database, it is possible one of them is changing the very data you are reading at the very instance that you are reading it. A transaction will help when there are two commands, such as 'Select Sum(BalanceDue) From Invoice Where CustomerId = 414' which is follwed by 'Select * From Invoice Where CustomerId = 414' and you don't want another user's transaction to change the values between those two commands. Of course, it does this by placing a read lock on that record which will affect performance.

Comment: I disagree with "No, it is not necessary".  It *may* be necesssary depending on the consistency you require for the reasons you give in your comment.

Comment: I did say it was useful. There are other ways to achieve consistency, such as throwing out inconsistent results and retrieving again. Since this technique is not the only one I don't think it can be called 'necessary,' especially since it negatively affects performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no need to do this. Transactions are only needed if you want to recover from error on an insert/update/delete operation. If you can't read something, tough luck, but data integrity won't be affected.